# iOSでTwitterアカウントへのアクセス可否を設定する画面を開く方法はありますか？

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

Accounts.frameworkを使って

```
// Twitterアカウントを取得する処理
let accountStore = ACAccountStore();
let twitterAccountType = accountStore.accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier(ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter);
let handler : ACAccountStoreRequestAccessCompletionHandler = { (granted, error) in
    if (!granted) {
        NSLog("拒否")
        self.showAlertMessage(
            "Twitterアカウントにアクセスできません",
            message: "設定 > プライバシー > Twitter からアクセスを許可してください")
    }
}
accountStore.requestAccessToAccountsWithType(twitterAccountType, options: nil, completion: handler);
```

こんな感じでTwitterアカウントにアクセスできなかったらalertを出して、設定ボタンから設定画面に誘導しようと思っています。

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!);
```

こんな感じに自分のアプリの設定画面を開くことはできますが、これだとTwitterの設定を変更する画面まで遠いので、
自分の設定画面に位置情報の許可のようにTwitterの設定をおいたりとか、なにかTwitterの設定へ誘導する良い方法はできないものでしょうか？

Comment: twitterのタグを追加しました。

Comment: できないと思います。上記のメッセージで「後で」と「設定へ」みたいなボタン付きのアラートに表示するのは最大できることかと思われます。

Comment: やっぱりそうですか。
Twitterログインを必須にしたアプリを作りたいので、認証まわりの導線をできるだけわかりやすく、短くしたいと思っているのですが。。

Answer (score 1):

自分のサイトで恐縮ですが、[こちらの方法](http://blog.praisefirst.jp/2014/06/swifttwitter_11.html)だと目的のことは達成できないでしょうか？

下図のダイアログが表示されます。

[image]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  let accountStore = ACAccountStore()
  let twitterAccountType = accountStore.accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier(ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter)
  let handler: ACAccountStoreRequestAccessCompletionHandler = {granted, error in
    if(!granted) {
      NSLog("ユーザーがアクセスを拒否しました。")
    } else {
      NSLog("ユーザーがアクセスを許可しました。")
    }
  }
  accountStore.requestAccessToAccountsWithType(twitterAccountType, handler)
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
この画面で許可しなかった、もしくは設定画面からオフにしているユーザに対して、アクセス許可をしてもらうのに一番わかりやすくて、短い導線を考えております。。。

Comment: 参照先を記載する際は引用し、回答内に転記するようにしてください。リンク先が存在し続ける保証が無い為です。

Comment: 転記は、このような形で合ってましたでしょうか？

Comment: はい、この書き方で問題ありません。